# Unity3D & C# - Какую часть языка нужно знать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Изучаю C#, но в дальнейшем планирую заниматься 2D играми на Unity3D.

Какую часть чистого C# языка нужно знать для того, чтобы смело идти в Unity3D и учить уже особенности самого движка?

Comment: понимать синтаксис языка. Знать паттерны нужные для игр.

Comment: По мне, так надо бы знать всё. Это, как минимум, даст простор для действий и возможность для выбора того или иного пути для реализаций задумок. Ограничение знания -> ограничение возможностей -> ограничение игры. имхо.

Comment: "чистый C#" учите весь, это не много и не долго, при желании, вам же потом легче будет.

Comment: Нужно знать язык и уметь его применять. Не стоит изучать все возможности содержащиеся нём - они будут изучаться по мере необходимости. Для начала определите что вам потребуется в первую очередь в Unity3D, кроме как работать с примитивами и массивами. На мой взгляд, если у вас будут Single проекты, то смысла нет учить сетевые функции языка. Это касается и всего остального. Зря потратите время на старте. Уделите его лучше оптимизации вашей писанины, ибо она в начале познания языка будет избыточна и содержать много некорректного кода для той ситуации в которой вы его используете.

Comment: Ничего... абсолютно ничего.
Поймите, знания в основном приходят с потребностью в этих знаниях. Будем откровены, вы напишите свой превый более менее завершенный проект, а потом еще раз -надцать его перепишите.
Если говорить про сам язык, то он по сути и не нужен в Unity, вы должны разбираться в алгоритмах и знать про базовые понятия из всех языков, ну там к примеру массивы, объекты, экземпляры и прочее. Unity это наверное самая не развитая в плане использования плюшек шарпа технология. В сравнении с другими - WPF, ASP, UWP, Xamarin. Почитайте Г. Шилдта - его хватит с лихвой. Еще Рихтера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы уверенно идти в Unity3D необходимо знать минимум основы языка C#, надо хотя бы понять его синтаксис. Вам точно пригодится создание массивов, класов и прочих объектов.  В глубь языка лезть не обязательно, но если у Вас будет больше опыта в этом языке, то Вам будет ещё легче создавать свой будущий шедевр. Поэтому если у Вас есть возможность учить язык, учите его полностью, ведь язык не может быть выучен по частям, язык это что-то целое и если вы хотите создавать даже простые игры Вам он понадобиться в полном объёме.

Answer (score 1):

В самую первую очередь почитай "Microsoft CTS", даже до изучения синтаксиса (прям с msdn'a читай). Это прямо верхушка и сама концепция языка. Сильно в msdn не углубляйся, т.к. там в основном фреймворк .net, а не голый c#.
После того как поймёшь концепцию языка начинай учить синтаксис.
После этого можно уже переходить к паттернам.

Answer (score 0):

Советую изучить C# полностью т.к. переменные, классы, массивы и прочие штуки C# пригодятся в юнити. Если не изучить будет сложно потом изучать юнити и понимать, что за что отвечает. Учи C# полностью. Почитай Герберт Шилдт полное руководство C# 4.0 и посмотри роликов в ютубе